# Есть ли такой тип данных в mysql?

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица (десятки миллионов строк), которая заполняется парсером. Есть поле description, в котором с высокой долей вероятности данные будут повторятся. Примеры строк:

```
"Эта строка повторяется 100000 раз"
"А эта 200 000 раз"
"Эта строка повторяется 1000 000 раз"
```

Заранее не известно, какие будут строки и сколько их будет. Поэтому тип данных ENUM не подходит.
Нужен такой тип данных, чтобы уменьшить объем данных на диске. Т. е. чтобы строка "Эта строка повторяется 100000 раз", например, по факту записывалась на диск один раз, а в остальных случаях записывалась на диск только ссылка на эту строку. Существует ли такой тип данных в mysql?

Можно кончено сделать еще одну таблицу с описаниями и ссылаться на нее с главной, но может уже есть какой-то тип данных, который справится с задачей без дополнительной таблицы? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> Можно кончено сделать еще одну таблицу с описаниями и ссылаться на нее с главной

Это единственно правильный выход

Comment: Это будет усложнять логику приложения, таких полей будет не мало. Мне кажется, что у разработчиков баз данных должна была возникнуть такая идея, надо только понять, куда копать

Comment: @РоманКистин Это не будет усложнять логику приложения, если данные читать не из таблицы, а из view

Comment: Как это сделать?) Уже нашел https://habr.com/ru/post/47031/

Comment: @РоманКистин В этом же и суть реляционных бд. Чтобы соеденить данные из двух таблиц напишите join. Разработчики подумали и дали вам возможность создавать отношения между данными в разных таблицах. Вы уже всё откопали :-)